Is past perfect the appropriate tense in this context?
Here is the context:

John retired last last year in January and he is still adjusting to retirement. He had been working since he was 16.

The alternative tense I'm considering is past continuous

He was working since he was 16.

My questions are:

Which one of these tenses is grammatically correct in this context?
Which tense conveys the best the connection between the long period of employment and the challenge adjusting to retirement.


The moment of his retiring is now in the past. At that point, his continuous stretch of working ended. But up to that point it was still intact, so the past perfect is the tense with which we, looking back at the moment of his retirement, would today describe the state of his working life as it was then.

When since is used with a specific starting time, it can only used with perfect tenses, i.e. tenses formed with have/has/had/had been/will have been, etc.


John's working is in the past.
You shouldn't use a continuous tense because John's working is over. It ended when he retired.
When since is used as a preposition that introduces a date or time in the past, it's typically used with present perfect or past perfect.

So you need past perfect.

John retired last year in January and he is still adjusting to retirement. He had worked since he was 16.

